# Array ordering logic based on another array key and direction (left or right)

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, logic, direction

I am facing a scenario where I need to order an array based on another array's index and direction (Left or Right). The crux of this ordering is that I have a set of charts ordered in horizontal axis based on an array. This horizontal arrangement is based on a webservice which shows history data. Similarly there is an option to view the real time values of the horizontal charts which is arranged as vertical(stack). Current logic is to create the vertical charts by iterating the array which forms the horizontal chart. But the issue is, on some cases this iteration involves another webservice call which causes order change. As a result the horizontal order does not matches with vertical order.

This is shown in the image attached.[Array Order Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RZ4Q.png).Here in the Chart Container, the charts come in an order and it is arranged according to its direction.

**Arrangement Logic in Chart container:**

1. When Chart Container is empty
   *Item A* with direction *Left*
   Output:  A(L)
   *Item B* with direction *Left*
   Output:  B(L)     A(L)
   *Item C* with direction *Right*
   Output:  B(L)     A(L)  C(R)
   etc..
2. **Expected arrangement logic in Chart List**
   L - Left Direction
   R- Right Direction

***Scenario- 1:***

If the current state is:  *20 10 30 40 50*
Direction of state    :                         *L  L R  R  R*

New item to be added: *60
L*

Expected order :        *60 20 10 30 40 50
L   L  L  R  R  R*

***Scenario-2***

If the current state is:  *10 20 30 40 50*
Direction of state    : *R  R R  R  R*

New item to be added: *60L*

Expected order :        *60 10 20 30 40 50*
Direction of order :     *L   R  R  R  R  R*

***Scenario-3***

If the current state is:  *50 40 30 20 10*
Direction of state    :   *L  L  L  L  L*

New item to be added: *60L*

Expected order :        *60 50 40 30 20 10*
Direction of order:*L  L  L  L  L  L*

***Scenario-4***

If the current state is: *50 40  20 10*
Direction of state    :   *L  L   L  L*

New item to be added: *30L*

Expected order :         *50 40 30 20 10*
Direction of order    :  *L  L  L  L  L*

***Scenario-5***

If the current state is:  50 40  20 10
Direction of state    :   L  L   R  R

New item to be added: *30L*

Expected order :         *50 40 30 20 10*
Direction of order:           *L  L  L  L  L*

I have created a stackblitz with my logic but that is not working in all the scenarios across. [Please check here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-ajax-f8aymx?file=index.html). In the stackblitz I have added possible dataset inside data folder.
Please check the link and help me to make this code work across all scenarios.
Thanks in advance. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: do you have only positive values?

Comment: Yes only positive. It is actually the index of the other array

Comment: @pilchard I am afraid I got your point. To me this is expected. Can you elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add all values to a main array and sort by direction and value.

```js
const
    log = o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)),
    sign = { L: -1, R: 1 },
    add = (values, insert) => [...values, insert].sort((a, b) =>
        (a[1] === 'R') - (b[1] === 'R') ||
        a[0] * sign[a[1]] - b[0] * sign[b[1]]
    );

log(add([[20, 'L'], [10, 'L'], [30, 'R'], [40, 'R'], [50, 'R']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 20 10 30 40 50 L L L R R R
log(add([[10, 'R'], [20, 'R'], [30, 'R'], [40, 'R'], [50, 'R']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 10 20 30 40 50 L R R R R R
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [30, 'L'], [20, 'L'], [10, 'L']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L L
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [20, 'L'], [10, 'L']], [30, 'L'])); // 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [20, 'R'], [10, 'R']], [30, 'L'])); // 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L
```

An approach without sorting. This approach needs a **sorted array** for finding the index.

```js
const
    log = o => console.log(JSON.stringify(o)),
    sign = { L: -1, R: 1 },
    add = (array, insert) => {
        let i = array.findIndex(([v, d]) => insert[0] * sign[insert[1]] < v * sign[d]);
        if (i === -1) array.push(insert)
        else array.splice(i, 0, insert);
        return array;
    };

log(add([[20, 'L'], [10, 'L'], [30, 'R'], [40, 'R'], [50, 'R']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 20 10 30 40 50 L L L R R R
log(add([[10, 'R'], [20, 'R'], [30, 'R'], [40, 'R'], [50, 'R']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 10 20 30 40 50 L R R R R R
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [30, 'L'], [20, 'L'], [10, 'L']], [60, 'L'])); // 60 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L L
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [20, 'L'], [10, 'L']], [30, 'L'])); // 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L
log(add([[50, 'L'], [40, 'L'], [10, 'R'], [20, 'R']], [30, 'L'])); // 50 40 30 20 10 L L L L L
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try it and update you.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid adding all values to a main array and sort. My intention is to insert the newly added item to its correct position rather than add it one array and sort. Is this possible? I am curious and sorry if I am wrong. At the end of the day in my actual use case I need to show this as a list in UI. So for that I may need to iterate it again. Right? Share your valuable thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the edited version. The logic seems to work and I guess this can be added to my actual use case. The trick to use direction as  negative and  positive one was really cool. It was not there in my mind. Thank you for your guidance.